# Styling every 3rd item of a list using CSS?

Tags: html, css

Is it possible for me to style every 3rd list item?

Currently in my `960px` wide div I have list of boxes which are floated left and are displayed in a 3x3 grid view. They also have a margin-right of `30px`, but because the 3rd 6th and 9th list item has this margin it makes them jump down a row making the grid display wrongly

How easy is to make the 3rd 6th and 9th not have the margin-right without having to give them a different class, or is that the only way to do it?

Comment: For better understanding this issue you can check this tutplus video
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nuCoBOdY2Qk
Thanks

Comment: You are looking for `li:nth-child(3n+3)` actually, since you want to exclude index 0. I'm surprised that the correct answer wasn't provided after five and a half years. Here is a [**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/WebWanderer/sjo3uu1z/6/)

Answer (score 267, accepted):

Yes, you can use what's known as [`:nth-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/:nth-child) selectors.

In this case you would use:

```
li:nth-child(3n) {
// Styling for every third element here.
}
```

**:nth-child(3n):**

```
3(0) = 0
3(1) = 3
3(2) = 6
3(3) = 9
3(4) = 12
```

`:nth-child()` is compatible in Chrome, Firefox, and IE9+.

For a work around to use `:nth-child()` amongst other pseudo-classes/attribute selectors in IE6 through to IE8, [see this link](http://selectivizr.com/).

Comment: does this option work in IE

Comment: @Gezzamondo According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/:nth-child) it is supported by IE9+.

Comment: It should work in IE9+. If you're after a work-around for IE8 and before, check this link out - http://selectivizr.com/

Comment: can i use a class on this

.work-grid:nth-child(3n) {
 width:300px;
 height:300px;
 margin-right:30px;
 margin-bottom:30px;
 background-color:#0C9;
 float:left;
 
}

Comment: I can't seem to get this to work. My li's have a class of .work-grid does this mean is cant use the :nth-child() ?

Comment: @Gezzamondo Did you check the accepted answer of the link I posted? It mentions there :)

Comment: yeah I had a read but it seemed a little confusing, some option they said worked didn't work for me

Comment: @Gezzamondo The accepted answer gives you your solution, look at what he does and how he targets a div with a specific class.

Comment: a bit confusing, what if it was a list though?

Comment: i tried that, have a look http://jsfiddle.net/BUWaZ/

Comment: @Gezzamondo Here you go :) - http://jsfiddle.net/BUWaZ/2/

Comment: It seems not working for me. Supose I have 6 element I want to grave every 3rd element then my works like:   :nth-child(4n -1){
            border-right: none;
        }

Answer (score 9):

You can use the [`:nth-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/:nth-child) selector for that

```
li:nth-child(3n) {
 /* your rules here */
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
box:nth-child(3n) {  
     ...
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Nwf2A/1/)

[`nth-child` browser support](http://caniuse.com/#search=nth-child)

Comment: +int(Pi/3) for brower support chart!

Answer (score 1):

`:nth-child` is the answer you are looking for.