# Is there an efficient way to create static wavy text?

Tags: html

(I'm really sorry if that's not the right way to phrase what I'm looking for.) 
I'm trying to create text that looks like this:

<sub>t</sub>h<sup>i</sup>s<sub>.</sub> F<sup>u</sup>r<sub>t</sub>h<sup>e</sup>r <sub>e</sub>x<sup>a</sup>m<sub>p</sub>l<sup>e</sup>.

It alternates subscript, normal, superscript, normal... etc. 
Currently, I'm writing it like this:

```
<sub>t</sub>h<sup>i</sup>s<sub>.</sub> F<sup>u</sup>r<sub>t</sub>h<sup>e</sup>r <sub>e</sub>x<sup>a</sup>m<sub>p</sub>l<sup>e</sup>.
```

I'm individually typing in each < sub > and < sup >. Is there a more efficient way to do this/create this effect? If so, what is it? If not, what are some alternatives? Thank you!

Comment: The most straightforward way to do this is probably via JavaScript.  CSS doesn't have a way to target individual characters within a span or p or other element, as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

#### Edit: :nth-child doesn't apply to text as they are not children.

Use the `:nth-child()` CSS selector. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13691714/17115294) for styling every third element. Then add the `vertical-align` property.

Comment: I'm not sure this works for letters within a tag, since they don't qualify as children of the containing element.

Comment: Thanks, I forgot about that. 

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with js.

```
testElem.innerHTML = 'string'.map(item => {
  if (item % 3) return `<sub>${item}</sub>`
  if (item % 2) return `<sup>${item}</sup>`
  return item
}).join('')
```

P. S. Why do you need it?

Answer (score 0):

I had fun coding this, but it's in JavaScript, not HTML or pure CSS.

```js
function wavyGravy(el, text) {

    const decorators = [
        "<sub>#</sub>",
        "<span style='text-transform: lowercase'>#</span>",
        "<span style='text-transform: uppercase'>#</span>", 
        "<sup>#</sup>",
        "<span style='text-transform: uppercase'>#</span>",
        "<span style='text-transform: lowercase'>#</span>"
    ]
    
    let it = 0;
    let innerHTML = "";
    text.split("").forEach(c => {
       innerHTML += (c === " ") ? c : decorators[it++%decorators.length].replace("#", c);
    })
    
    el.innerHTML = innerHTML;
}
```

```html
<div id='parent-element'>This is a sample text!</div>
<button onClick="wavyGravy(document.getElementById('parent-element'), 'This is a groovy sample text!')">
Click me!
</button>
```

Basically what you do is provide a parent element and a text you want to transform. For example if you have an element with the ID "this-element" and want a text "Groovy text!" then you call

```
let el = document.findElementById("this-element");
const text = "Groovy text!";
wavyGravy(el, text);
```